# Salesforce community portal not loading on Edge (Windows 10) & Safari (Mac ) browser

Tags: community

Salesforce community portal not loading on Edge (Windows 10) & Safari-v7.0.2 (Mac 10.9.2) browser.

Community portal in created on Sandbox and the site's SSL certificates are also verified & are valid.

Template used is Napili & for community pages we are using Lightning Components.

Not sure why these browsers are blocking our Community Portal. Kindly tell me what may be causing this issue.

Edge Browser - Community Home Page - console.
[image]

Safari Browser - Login Page - console
[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful for you to explain what "not loading" means. Are you seeing an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: I have added the screenshots of console messages from both browsers, now the community portal is loading on Edge browser but on console log it shows me the above errors. But on Safari browser the login page itself does not load, may be I need to try latest Safari browser in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser support is limited to the latest versions:

> If you use Safari, we recommend using the latest version that Salesforce supports. Apply all Apple software updates.
>
> Salesforce currently doesn't support Analytics with Apple Safari. Use Internet Explorer 11, Edge, or the latest version of Chrome or Firefox.
>
> Salesforce supports the latest version of Microsoft Edge for both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience. However, the Developer Console doesn't support Microsoft Edge.

Safari 7 was released in 2013. The latest Safari requires at least macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

**References**

- [Considerations for Apple Safari](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_considerations_safari.htm&type=5)
- [Considerations for Microsoft Edge](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_considerations_edge.htm&type=5)
- [About the security content of Safari 6.1.2 and Safari 7.0.2 - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202921)
- [Apple security updates - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222)
- [Apple introduces Safari 7 with design tweaks, memory, social improvements, iCloud Keychain and more - 9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2013/06/10/apple-introduces-safari-7-with-design-tweaks-memory-social-improvements-and-more/)
- [List of web browsers - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers)